solr error SolrException: Error loading solr config from C:\SOLR\solr-9.6.1\core_name\conf\solrconfig.xml Please check your logs for more information
Being new to solr, I recently came across this error in my Solr Admin UI:

core_name:
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
Could not load conf for core core_name: Error loading solr config from
C:\Users\SOLR\solr-9.6.1\core_name\conf\solrconfig.xml Please check
your logs for more information

The problem first arose when I tried creating a core without initializing the xml file before.


Inital issue and origin:

After digging a little bit around, I found some answers that pointed me to check if the configuration files exist in the new core folder of Solr. Since I created the core from Admin UI, even though it threw the error:
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'core_name': Unable to create core [core_name] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'C:\Users\SOLR\solr-9.6.1\core_name
The folder was still created inside my solr directory and it was empty. So there were two ways to solve it. First was to create the file it was looking for, the config file. Second way was to delete the core and start fresh. I just deleted the folder from directory manually and that's when I started seeing the error mentioned in the question.

What worked?

What worked for me was to delete the core from my command prompt using
solr delete -c core_name


The power of command line prompts:

Instead of creating the core from Admin UI, if we create it in cmd, we won't have to explicitly create the config xml file. It will be generated for us. We can create a core using:
solr create -c core_name

